# How can I get the connected route from a URL string in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes, slug

CakePHP appears to have a function to translate a requested URL and determine what controller and action to perform, seeing this must be performed with each http request.

Is there a way I can utilize this process within a controller or elsewhere in the system? The best outcome would be to have a function where I input a URL string, and the response is an array with controller details. eg:

```
$url_route = RouteFunction('/page/url/here');

// $url_route = array(
//    'controller' => 'page', 
//    'action' => 'display', 
//    'pass' => array('url', 'here')
// );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use [`Router::parse()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Router.html#_parse).

For example:

```
$route = Router::parse('/users/view/21');
debug($route);
```

will by default output:

```
array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'view',
    'named' => array(),
    'pass' => array(
            (int) 0 => '21'
    ),
    'plugin' => null
)
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was after, I just couldn't find the function. Thanks.